# After updates in 14.04 boots to black screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, virtualbox, xorg

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a VirtualBox and I've done updates to the Ubuntu install today. After a reboot I get a black screen after login. I have another VBox of 14.04 without any updates and it works fine. I'm assuming the updates have caused the issue.

I've done some of the attempts at fixing with GRUB remove `splash quiet`, remove .Xauthority, use boot-repair (I get `Gtk-warning cannot open display`).

*I can't create a new install because I'll lose all of my data and programs.*

Help!

Comment: Can you give more information on the GPU your system is using and if TTY1 Ctrl][Alt][F1] is available?

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I've got this fixed. For anyone else stuck here was the solution

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

good luck out there!

Comment: Two things - you probably don't need the add-apt-repository line. But also, this didn't work for me, my stack is VirtualBox on OSX. And Ubuntu 12.04 works perfectly. Still searching for a solution on this one. I can use the virtualbox by SSH'ing in, so it's not a dead loss, but still.